# method [showpath] does not exist on [FirstProject\Http\Controllers\UserController]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, controllers, laravel-middleware

Hello i am learning laravel for first time on topic controllers.I need to get this output

First Middleware,
Second Middleware,
URI: usercontroller/path,
URL: http://localhost:8000/usercontroller/path,
Method: GET

My Following codes are:

UserControler.php

```
namespace FirstProject\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use FirstProject\Http\Requests;
use FirstProject\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }    
}
```

FirstMiddleware.php

```
namespace FirstProject\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FirstMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo "<br>First Middleware";
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

SecondMiddleware.php

```
namespace FirstProject\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SecondMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo "<br>Second Middleware";
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

SecondUserController.php

```
namespace FirstProject\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use FirstProject\Http\Requests;
use FirstProject\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SecondUserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
      $this->middleware('Second');
   }
   public function showPath(Request $request){
      $uri = $request->path();
      echo '<br>URI: '.$uri;

      $url = $request->url();
      echo '<br>';

      echo 'URL: '.$url;
      $method = $request->method();
      echo '<br>';

      echo 'Method: '.$method;
   }
}
```

Routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/usercontroller/path',[
   'middleware' => 'First',
   'uses' => 'UserController@showPath'
]);
```

But When im running http://localhost:8000/usercontroller/path

I m getting 
BadMethodCallException
Method [showPath] does not exist on [FirstProject\Http\Controllers\UserController].

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite obvious, isn't it ?  This method is defined in `SecondUserController` but not in `UserController` and in routes you use `'UserController@showPath'`

Comment: Yes but as in tutorials,it was told to create controller UserController but it came it already exists,tht is why i had to create different controller name.

Comment: any other help?

Comment: So when you changed your controller name you should also change the controller name in your `web.php` file. Now you refer in this file into not existing `showPath` method in `UserController` and that's why you are getting the error.